# Are the Battlefield 1 Expansion Packs Campaigns or just Multiplayer Maps?

Tags: battlefield-1

I just played Battlefield 1 on PS4 and loved it. I am looking into getting the expansion packs but from the marketing material it is not clear whether these are just new multiplayer maps and weapons or campaigns. I am hoping for more campaigns like the 6 stories in the main game (e.g. "Friends in High Places" or "The Runner").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DLC are all pure multiplayer, introducing new maps, guns, and game modes. Unfortunately there aren't any new/additional War Stories.

If you haven't done so, you should still try the **Operations** game mode, which essentially plays pretty much like the Italian War Story (which uses one of the maps). They also tell small stories and progress over a map, but they're still a player vs player experience.